# Getting xml:id attribute using XML object

Tags: javascript, xml, rhino, e4x

I'm processing XML using Rhino 1.7R3 and have trouble accessing `xml:id` attribute.

```js
var bond = new XML('<person xml:id="007" profession="agent">James Bond</person>');
print(bond); // "James Bond"
print(bond.@profession); // "agent"
print(bond.@xml:id); // ERROR: missing ) after argument list
```

I tried putting `xml:id` inside quotes and square brackets but it didn't solve the problem. Is there a way?

---

**EDIT**: I got it working by defining namespace. After that both of the methods Siva suggests work:

```js
var xml = new Namespace("xml", "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace");
var bond = new XML('<person xml:id="007" profession="agent">James Bond</person>');
print(bond); // "James Bond"
print(bond.@profession); // "agent"
print(bond.@xml::id); // "007"
print(bond..@xml::id); // "007"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way

```
print(bond.@xml::id);
```

or

```
print(bond..@xml::id);
```

Comment: If you want to know what's happening here, it's that you're matching an `id` attribute in the predefined [`xml` namespace](http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace), which is always http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace and must always have prefix `xml`. You can declare other namespaces with `prefix = "uri"` or `var prefix = new Namespace('uri')` and then match with `prefix::`

Comment: Siva & Francis, I got it working by combining your suggestions. Thanks.